# In Excel, how could I fill in other columns with parts of another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one column created with 5 or 6 digits in the cells with a plus sign two from the last digit (ex. 000+00; 0000+00). I need to create two other columns, one with what's on the left side of the plus sign, and one with what's on it's right side. I wouldn't mind doing it by hand, but there's 103,711 entries... anyone have any ideas?!

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions mentioned in the OP:

1. There will always be either 3 or 4 digits before the plus sign
2. There will always be a plus sign
3. There will always be 2 digits after the plus sign

If A1 is the cell with the full text, in the cells for left side:

```
=if(len(A1)=6, left(A1,3), left(A1,4))
```

In those for the right side:

```
=right(A1,2)
```

Here's a good function reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-functions-by-category-HP005204211.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution. These formulas obtain the position of the "+" in each string and then use that number to obtain the left and right substrings (regardless of their length).

**Left Side:**

```
=LEFT(A1,SEARCH("+",A1)-1)
```

**Right Side:**

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("+",A1))
```

Or if each of the entries only have 2 characters to the right of the "+", Jonathan's formula would be better: `=RIGHT(A1,2)`